# Need to cut a 1' hole through bookshelf-right tool?

Tags: tool-selection

I'm converting an old entertainment unit into a huge cage for my ferrets and I'm trying to figure out how to cut a one foot hole through each end to thread and secure tubes leading up the the top where I'll build a run for them.

What tool do i need to cut through about a quarter inch of plywood? Pressed board? (Latter i think)

Also bonus question but unimportant (I'll Finegal my way through it otherwise) I'm using 1' high dryer tube for the tunnels from top to bottom-how would *you* secure it to the openings of the hole I'll eventually cut, up to a wire cage run on top? Like a sideways U leading from the top cage run to the bottom wood sleeping area.

Comment: If you're set on buying a jigsaw for this you only need to drill one hole to start the blade in, not a series of holes around the circumference. Also note the up/down action of a jigsaw blade makes it prone to catching and lifting sheet goods so you're going to want to firmly support the board as much as possible during the cut (same deal regardless if you're cutting plywood or hardboard, but the latter can tend to be more friable).

Answer (score 1):

The usual way is to mark the circle, drill some small holes around the inside, connect the holes using a jigsaw, use rasps, files or sandpaper to bring the cut-out to desired dimensions.

You can buy or make a jig that rigidly connects the jigsaw to a rail whose length is the desired radius and that pivots around a pin, screw, nail or bolt at the desired centre of the circular cutout.

A websearch for "jigsaw cutting circle" will find many examples.

Comment: Thank you so much! Been trying to work it out from scratch-appreciate the help!

Comment: Funny thing.  I was thinking of the second method you mentioned as "the usual way".  I guess "usual" depends on your personal experience :).